# VSTS build looking for a drive that doesn't exist

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am setting up three build and release pipelines in VSTS. My first two for QA and Staging are working fine. My production build though seems to be looking for an F: drive to publish my website to, which does not exist. The other two pipelines publish successfully to the E: drives. I'm deploying the same branch to each server.

I cannot for the life of me work out why this is so. Any ideas anybody?

log is below:

```
>    2018-09-07T10:39:12.9818031Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy IIS
> Website/App:  2018-09-07T10:39:12.9824407Z
> ============================================================================== 2018-09-07T10:39:12.9824537Z Task         : IIS Web App Deploy
> 2018-09-07T10:39:12.9824635Z Description  : Deploy a Website or Web
> Application using WebDeploy 2018-09-07T10:39:12.9824748Z Version     
> : 0.0.42 2018-09-07T10:39:12.9824833Z Author       : Microsoft
> Corporation 2018-09-07T10:39:12.9824934Z Help         : [More
> Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866789)
> 2018-09-07T10:39:12.9825405Z
> ============================================================================== 2018-09-07T10:39:15.0081829Z [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft
> Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync
> -source:package='C:\vstsagent\A1\_work\r1\a\Production Build - Azure\drop\ThisIsMyWebsiteName.Mvc.zip' -dest:auto -setParam:name='IIS
> Web Application Name',value='www.ThisIsMyWebsiteName.org.uk'
> 2018-09-07T10:39:16.2102044Z Info: Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
> 2018-09-07T10:39:16.2957835Z Info: Adding virtual path
> (www.ThisIsMyWebsiteName.org.uk) 2018-09-07T10:39:16.3117823Z Info:
> Adding directory (www.ThisIsMyWebsiteName.org.uk).
> 2018-09-07T10:39:16.3666499Z Error: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web
> Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295
> 2018-09-07T10:39:16.3666959Z     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
> (C:\vstsagent\A1\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.0.42\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\toolrunner.js:569:30)
> 2018-09-07T10:39:16.3667253Z     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
> 2018-09-07T10:39:16.3667459Z     at ChildProcess.emit
> (events.js:191:7) 2018-09-07T10:39:16.3667643Z     at maybeClose
> (internal/child_process.js:886:16) 2018-09-07T10:39:16.3667842Z     at
> Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
> 2018-09-07T10:39:16.3744137Z ##[warning]Can\'t find loc string for
> key: RetryToDeploy 2018-09-07T10:39:16.3756406Z RetryToDeploy
> 2018-09-07T10:39:16.3758339Z [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft
> Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync
> -source:package='C:\vstsagent\A1\_work\r1\a\Production Build - Azure\drop\ThisIsMyWebsiteName.Mvc.zip' -dest:auto -setParam:name='IIS
> Web Application Name',value='www.ThisIsMyWebsiteName.org.uk'
> 2018-09-07T10:39:16.9979596Z Info: Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
> 2018-09-07T10:39:17.0833918Z Info: Adding virtual path
> (www.ThisIsMyWebsiteName.org.uk) 2018-09-07T10:39:17.1024603Z Info:
> Adding directory (www.ThisIsMyWebsiteName.org.uk).
> 2018-09-07T10:39:17.1479924Z Error: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web
> Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295
> 2018-09-07T10:39:17.1480586Z     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
> (C:\vstsagent\A1\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.0.42\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\toolrunner.js:569:30)
> 2018-09-07T10:39:17.1480827Z     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
> 2018-09-07T10:39:17.1481001Z     at ChildProcess.emit
> (events.js:191:7) 2018-09-07T10:39:17.1481193Z     at maybeClose
> (internal/child_process.js:886:16) 2018-09-07T10:39:17.1481404Z     at
> Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
> 2018-09-07T10:39:17.1482037Z ##[warning]Can\'t find loc string for
> key: RetryToDeploy 2018-09-07T10:39:17.1482506Z RetryToDeploy
> 2018-09-07T10:39:17.1486722Z [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft
> Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync
> -source:package='C:\vstsagent\A1\_work\r1\a\Production Build - Azure\drop\ThisIsMyWebsiteName.Mvc.zip' -dest:auto -setParam:name='IIS
> Web Application Name',value='www.ThisIsMyWebsiteName.org.uk'
> 2018-09-07T10:39:17.7446787Z Info: Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
> 2018-09-07T10:39:17.8281962Z Info: Adding virtual path
> (www.ThisIsMyWebsiteName.org.uk) 2018-09-07T10:39:17.8451236Z Info:
> Adding directory (www.ThisIsMyWebsiteName.org.uk).
> 2018-09-07T10:39:17.8859246Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to
> IIS website. 2018-09-07T10:39:17.8873159Z ##[error]Error: An error was
> encountered when processing operation 'Create Directory' on
> 'F:\Websites\www.ThisIsMyWebsiteName.org.uk\wwwroot'. Error: The error
> code was 0x80070002. Error: Could not find file '\\?\F:'. Error count:
> 1.
> 
> 2018-09-07T10:39:17.8884343Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program
> Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return
> code: 4294967295 2018-09-07T10:39:17.9217040Z ##[section]Finishing:
> Deploy IIS Website/App:
```

Comment: Have you looked at the parameters you're providing to the deployment scripts? Have you validated whether or not the website in IIS exists already, and if so, what directory it's pointing to?

Comment: Thank you @DanielMann - it's always the bit you didn't do yourself - the path in IIS was incorrect. Couldn't see it for looking.